Problems to install QGIS on Debian 11 (Bullseye) after 25/October/2024
I have been used QGIS-ltr in Debian 11 for a long time, but QGIS vanished of my computer at October 27, 2024.
I have limited knowledge about Debian.
Then, I ran "sudo apt autoremove" and tried install QGIS-ltr following "https://qgis.org/resources/installation-guide/#debianubuntu", but it did not work. Messages of unmet dependencies were showed.

I have tried install QGIS-ltr in another computer (also using Debian 11) and get same results.
I suspect that it happened after Debian updates.
I looked to /var/log/dpkg.log and notice that distro-info-data were upgraded in October 25, 2024. Because of my limited knowledge, I can't say that this things are correlated.
How can I fix it? Is it happening only to me?
UPDATE
I downgraded distro-info-data and it didn't solve.
I tried install QGIS-Latest Release and it worked. This installation use another repository. Are there something wrong to QGIS-ltr repository or am I making mistakes when I try install QGIS-ltr? The difference about two installations I have being done is just at qgis.sources file. For QGIS-Latest Release I have using "URIs: https://qgis.org/debian" and for QGIS-ltr I have using "URIs: https://qgis.org/debian-ltr".
